# windows mobile 5.0 using GPS intermediate driver giving always lat lon as 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, gps, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-gps

Hi I am using the GPS sample which comes with CE tools.

I already got rid of divide by zero error, but the GPS intermediate driver always gives latitude and longitude as 0.

I can see my GPS device is on and receiving the signal. Other application like GPS Monitor, global navigator are giving me right lat lon.

Can any one please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: as i menctioned i am just using sample code

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158708.aspx

Comment: GpsPosition position = gps.GetPosition();
            //if (position.LatitudeValid)                                   
            lbllat.Text = position.LatitudeInDegreesMinutesSeconds.ToString();
            //if (position.LongitudeValid)
            lbllong.Text = position.LongitudeInDegreesMinutesSeconds.ToString();

Comment: That doesn't look like the code from the sample, as you've no event handler? You also mentioned you "got rid of a divide by zero error", but you have no division in the code you mention?

Comment: this one i pasted here is different, this is just a button click event i am using like a different project just to see what data i am receiving

Comment: I found [Microsoft's Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158708.aspx), but it states to include the `using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Samples.Location;` directive. That doesn't exist on my machine. Did I get the wrong WM6 SDK? I found the example in Program Files, but none of the objects that it compiled to were able to go into my WM6 project. ???

Comment: Hi, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389 gives  you the mentioned SDK but even using that one my device is not giving any information using that sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, First for windows mobile 5.0 we need to use sample code from "C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\" and the next and important this is we need to use right port and especially right baud rate, with out that you can't get the signal,

Thanks All
Srikanth